# How can I install Eclipse 4 through Ubuntu Software Center (desktop 12.04 64bit)?

Tags: software-center, eclipse

How do I install Eclipse 4 through Ubuntu Software Center on my desktop 12.04 64 bit os?

The reason I would like to install through Ubuntu Software Center is because it's easy to uninstall the software, and i want to manage all my installed programs through the Software Center.

If I have to install through other means, will Eclipse show up in Ubuntu Software Center?

Thanks for any help.

### Update: Clarification

I did find Eclipse but it was version 3.7. I'm looking to install version 4.

Comment: be warned, there are loads of bugs associated with the portable install

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, Eclipse 4 is not currently (as of 12.04) available through the Ubuntu repositories and as a result you can't install it through the software center. However, as Eclipse runs contained within it's own directory, you should be able to just download Eclipse 4, extract it to a directory somewhere and run the IDE.

If you want a menu launcher for it, I would suggest searching for and installing "alacarte" (I believe it's called "Main Menu" in your apps list) in the software center. You can create a menu item manually for Eclipse with that app.

Comment: Menu launcher? what do you mean by that. Is that like adding it to the "start" menu? (sorry for windows terminology... lol)

Comment: Sorry, by menu launcher, I meant the equivalent of an icon or shortcut within a Windows Start menu. Does that make sense?

Comment: @quakkels Yes you create a "start menu item" the you should be able to find it with the Dash (click on ubuntu button at the top left). When it is running you can right click and lock it to the launcher.